# Random value with student t

Tags: r, distribution, variance

I would like to get some random values ​​from a student t with specific mean and variance.
Is it right to use  the command `rt = (n, df, ncp)` to have two random samples with different variance? Do I have to vary the degrees of freedom?
example:

```
rt=(n=30,df=5)
rt=(n=20,df=10)
```

Comment: `rt` is a function generating Student-t distributed variables. See `help("rt")`.

Comment: yes yes exactly, I want to obtain Student-t distributed.
I want to generate two variables with the same mean but with different variance. how should i set the parameters of the `rt` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rt` function follows the standard convention of the Student's t distribution which has it centered (mean 0) and the only parameter is the degrees of freedom. [See the wikipedia page on the distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution) for more explanation. If you want different means, you can add whatever mean you want to the 0-centered random variables you generate with `rt()`. As Wikipedia shows, the variance `v = df / (df - 2)` where `df` is the degrees of freedom, so you can solve for what `df` you need to get a specific variance.

For example, if you wanted a t-distributed random variable with mean 5 and variance 1.2, we can solve `1.2 = df / (df - 2)` to get `df = 12`, and generate 100 samples with `rt(n = 100, df = 12) + 5`.